# How can you get a list of your friend's Instagram followers with Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-api

I am using LevPasha’s Unofficial Instagram API. I know that this is a method to get the list of my own followers:

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

username = "username"
profile = InstagramAPI(username, "password")
profile.login()
user_id = profile.username_id

followers = InstagramAPI.getTotalFollowers(profile, user_id)
```

How can I do this for a different user without their password (it does not have to be with this specific API)?

Answer (score 2):

Officially there is no support for your requirement.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

Don't use packages or codes that consumes user's original password. That is a poor way.
Your account can be easily hacked by others. This is not a recommended way.